# Implement forelse control in native php

Tags: php

Laravel blade templating language has a really useful @forelse control structure that turns:

```
@if (count($results))
    @foreach ($results as $result)
        ...
    @endforeach
@else
    echo "No results found";
@endif
```

into

```
@forelse ($results as $result)
    ...
@empty
    echo "No results found";
@endforelse
```

Is there a way to implement this in native PHP?  I am constantly using the if(count), foreach, else structure.  I'd like a way for this to work:

```
forelse ($results as $result) {
     ...
} empty {
    echo "No results found";
}
```

Is PHP extensible enough for this to be implemented without messing with the interpreter itself?

Comment: if you want it to be in php you can make a rfc for that - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/howto - and ask if anyone could help you implementing it

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979448/difference-between-foreach-and-forelse-in-laravel which has a great breakdown of the source

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not currently implementable.  But there is a proposal to do so:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/loop_else