# How to fix Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '['?

Tags: php, laravel

```
 @extends('admin.layouts.app_admin')

@section('content') 

<div class="container">

     @component('admin.components.breadcrumb')
        @slot('title') all_ category @endslot
        @slot('parent') main @endslot
        @slot('active') category @endslot
    @endcomponent 
    <hr>


 <a href="{{route('admin.category.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square-0">Создать категорию</i></a>
        <table class="table table-striped">
                <th>XXX</th>
                <th>XXX</th>
                <th class="text-right">XXX</th>
<tbody>
                @forelse ($categories as category)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$category->title}}</td>
                    <td>{{$category->published}}</td>
                    <td>
                         <a href="{{route('admin.category.edit', ['id'=>$category->id])}}"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @empty
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-center"><h2>not found</h2></td>
                </tr>
                @endforelse
            </tbody>
        </table>

</div>

 @endsection
```

I have such an error in this file
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '[' (View: D: \ wamp \ www \ blog \ resources \ views \ admin \ categories \ index.blade.php)
please help me solve it, I already broke my head, I can’t find the error

even if the file is empty, it still gives this error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979448/difference-between-foreach-and-forelse-in-laravel   forelse not a problem, because if file is empty, it still gives this error

Comment: I doubt that is the full error message. You removed the line number. Why? How do you expect us to help if you do not point out that line the error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the category variable properly

```
@forelse ($categories as $category)
```

Hope this helps